# PHP object notation generator similar to json

Tags: php

I have some data structure in PHP that I need to dump into a format that can be natively parsed as PHP code. Is there a tool for that?

In other words, is there a PHP data structure formatter that would output PHP object notation code, a sort of "PSON" for PHP similar to what JSON is for JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use build in function [`var_export`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

Comment: Thanks! I was just able to get `var_export()` to work with this kludgy workaround: `str_replace("stdClass::__set_state", "(object)", var_export($data, true))`

Answer (score 1):

There is, it is called serialize: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Sorry but `serialize()` outputs some format that is not PHP code, it is only readable by calling `unserialize()`.

Comment: var_export produces executable code, but is not well suited for objects, especially built-in classes - they need to have static function `__set_state` or produced code with fail with fatal error. The best you can do is to wrap output of 'serialize' into `unserialize` function and you will have native executable.

Comment: @rustyx . I think both answers are correct. What is wrong with calling unserialize? Also read dev-null-dwellers comment